# Where is the Overlay dropdown in Blender 2.9? it appears to be gone from the viewport

Tags: 3d-view, interface, shortcut

Does anyone know where the Overlays drop down is in the newer blender updates? or if I somehow deleted it, and how to recover it?
both my Blender 2.83 and Blender 2.9 don't seem to[image] have the drop down I see in a tutorial I am trying to follow. Google has been no help

Comment: you need to click on the down arrow on the right of the Overlay icon (double sphere, blue when enabled), doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much I saw that there was no normal editing when I first clicked that so thought it was a different menu until I realized I was not in editing mode hurdur lol.

Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 7):

The text "Overlays" has been removed but the button is still there. There is just a small down pointing arrow.

[image: Overlays]

Comment: Thank you very much I saw that there was no normal editing when I first clicked that so thought it was a different menu until I realized I was not in editing mode hurdur lol.

Thank you very much again.

Comment: feels like the 2.8 -> 2.9 changes mostly served just to make things hard to find again